# Why this COUNT in HAVING not working expectedly?

Tags: mysql

I am using following query to select all those customers who appears more than 3 times with their status id. The query also count number of times a status id appears for a customer:

```
SELECT `bp_customer_id`, `status_id`, COUNT(`status_id`) FROM `bp_orders` 
GROUP BY `status_id`, `bp_customer_id` 
ORDER BY `bp_customer_id`
```

It gives following output:

[image]

In the above table, the customer 1000 appears 3 times. So I want to select only those customers who appears 3 or more than 3 times in the table. How do we do that? I used `COUNT()` and `HAVING` in above query but no luck.

```
SELECT `bp_customer_id`, `status_id`, COUNT(`status_id`) FROM `bp_orders` 
GROUP BY `status_id`, `bp_customer_id` 
HAVING COUNT(`bp_customer_id`) >= 3 
ORDER BY `bp_customer_id`
```

[image]

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your expectation is only the `bp_customer_id` or `bp_customer_id` along with `status_id`, `COUNT(\`status_id\`)` ?

Comment: @Arulkumar, `bp_customer_id` along with `status_id`, `COUNT`... all of them

Comment: ``​SELECT `bp_customer_id`, `status_id`, COUNT(`status_id`) FROM `bp_orders` WHERE `bp_customer_id` IN (SELECT `bp_customer_id` FROM `bp_orders` GROUP BY `bp_customer_id` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `status_id`) >= 3) GROUP BY `status_id`, `bp_customer_id` ORDER BY `bp_customer_id`​``

Comment: @PetSerAl Great! That's what I was searching for. Thanks.

Comment: @user5307298 I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56439565/2451726) as per your comment

Answer (score 0):

If you are need only `bp_customer_id` in the output result, ignore the other columns in the `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT `bp_customer_id`
FROM `bp_orders` 
GROUP BY `bp_customer_id` 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `bp_customer_id`) >= 3 
ORDER BY `bp_customer_id`
```

As per your comment, you need `bp_customer_id` along with status_id and COUNT. So using the above query as sub query and based on the `bp_customer_id` you can get the other details too. So the working query is:

```
​SELECT `bp_customer_id`, 
       `status_id`, 
       COUNT(`status_id`) 
FROM `bp_orders` 
WHERE `bp_customer_id` IN (
    SELECT `bp_customer_id`
    FROM `bp_orders` 
    GROUP BY `bp_customer_id` 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `bp_customer_id`) >= 3 
) 
GROUP BY `bp_customer_id`, `status_id` 
ORDER BY `bp_customer_id`
```

Comment: The second version of your solution is almost correct except that you still have fetched those customers who have only one type of status ids. For example, customers 232 and 999 etc. have only one status id. PetSerAl has done exactly what I needed.

Comment: ``​COUNT(DISTINCT `bp_customer_id`)​`` can not be more then 1 with ``​GROUP BY `bp_customer_id`​``.

Comment: @Arulkumar not right yet. In fact, you should have done `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT \`status_id\`) >= 3 )`

Answer (score 0):

haven't checked if this will work but doing a sub select might help

```
SELECT A.`bp_customer_id`, A.`status_id`, COUNT(`status_id`) FROM `bp_orders` A, {
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS customerCount, `bp_customer_id` FROM `bp_orders` GROUP BY `bp_customer_id`
} B WHERE A.`bp_customer_id` = B.`bp_customer_id`
AND B.customerCount >= 3
GROUP BY A.`status_id`, A.`bp_customer_id` 
ORDER BY A.`bp_customer_id`
```

Comment: But why your query selects rows with `bp_customer_id` 232, 999... which appears only once for a specific `status_id`. It's not correct.